# MySQL count rows with similar timestamp

Tags: mysql

Is there anyway to count a given run of timestamps that are close to each other, but not necessarily in a fixed time frame?

Ie, not grouped by hour or minute, but rather grouped by how close the current row's timestamp is to the next row's timestamp. If the next row is within "x" seconds/minutes then add that row to the group, otherwise start a new grouping.

Given this data:

```
+----+---------+---------------------+
| id | item_id | event_date          |
+----+---------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 | 2013-05-17 11:59:59 |
|  2 |       1 | 2013-05-17 12:00:00 |
|  3 |       1 | 2013-05-17 12:00:02 |
|  4 |       1 | 2013-05-17 12:00:03 |
|  5 |       3 | 2013-05-17 14:05:00 |
|  6 |       3 | 2013-05-17 14:05:01 |
|  7 |       3 | 2013-05-17 15:30:00 |
|  8 |       3 | 2013-05-17 15:30:01 |
|  9 |       3 | 2013-05-17 15:30:02 |
| 10 |       1 | 2013-05-18 09:12:00 |
| 11 |       1 | 2013-05-18 09:13:30 |
| 12 |       1 | 2013-05-18 09:13:45 |
| 13 |       1 | 2013-05-18 09:14:00 |
| 14 |       2 | 2013-05-20 15:45:00 |
| 15 |       2 | 2013-05-20 15:45:03 |
| 16 |       2 | 2013-05-20 15:45:10 |
| 17 |       2 | 2013-05-23 07:36:00 |
| 18 |       2 | 2013-05-23 07:36:10 |
| 19 |       2 | 2013-05-23 07:36:12 |
| 20 |       2 | 2013-05-23 07:36:15 |
| 21 |       1 | 2013-05-24 11:55:00 |
| 22 |       1 | 2013-05-24 11:55:02 |
+----+---------+---------------------+
```

Desired Results:

```
+---------+-------+---------------------+
| item_id | total | last_date_in_group  |
+---------+-------+---------------------+
|       1 |     4 | 2013-05-17 12:00:03 |
|       3 |     2 | 2013-05-17 14:05:01 |
|       3 |     3 | 2013-05-17 15:30:02 |
|       1 |     4 | 2013-05-18 09:14:00 |
|       2 |     3 | 2013-05-20 15:45:10 |
|       2 |     4 | 2013-05-23 07:36:15 |
|       1 |     2 | 2013-05-24 11:55:02 |
+---------+-------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little complicated.  To start, you need is time of the next event for each record.  The following subquery adds in such a time (`nexted`), if it is within bounds:

```
 select t.*,
         (select event_date
          from t t2
          where t2.item_id = t.item_id and
                t2.event_date > t.event_date and
                <date comparison here>
          order by event_date limit 1
         ) as nexted
  from t
```

This uses a correlated subquery.  The `<date comparison here>` is for whatever date comparison you want.  When there is no record, the value will be NULL.

Now, with this information (`nexted`) there is a trick to get the grouping.  For any record, it is the first event time afterwards where `nexted` is NULL.  This will be the last event in the series.  Unfortunately, this requires two levels of nested correlated subqueries (or joins with aggregations).  The result looks a bit unwieldy:

```
select item_id, GROUPING, MIN(event_date) as start_date, MAX(event_date) as end_date,
       COUNT(*) as num_dates
from (select t.*,
             (select min(t2.event_date)
              from (select t1.*,
                           (select event_date
                            from t t2
                            where t2.item_id = t1.item_id and
                                  t2.event_date > t1.event_date and
                                  <date comparison here>
                            order by event_date limit 1
                           ) as nexted
                    from t1
                   ) t2
              where t2.nexted is null
             ) as grouping
      from t
     ) s
group by item_id, grouping;
```

Comment: This looks promising, thanks for your help! I just have one question regarding the <date comparison>. I'm assuming if i wanted a max of 1 minute gap, it would look something like (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2.event_date)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.event_date)) < 3600 ?

Comment: @tburnside . . . Yes, I think that is right for MySQL.  To be honest, the date/time functions in MySQL always confuse me, so I find myself going back to the documentation a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What about approaching it from finding each individual record's local associations, and then grouping on the max event date from each record's discoveries. This is based on a static differential time interval (5 minutes in my example)

```
SELECT item_id, MAX(total), MAX(last_date_in_group) AS last_date_in_group FROM (
    SELECT t1.item_id, COUNT(*) AS total, COALESCE(GREATEST(t1.event_date, MAX(t2.event_date)), t1.event_date) AS last_date_in_group
        FROM table_name t1
        LEFT JOIN table_name t2 ON t2.event_date BETWEEN t1.event_date AND t1.event_date + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
        GROUP BY t1.id
    ) t
    GROUP BY last_date_in_group
```

Comment: The run of timestamps may or may not be in the same minute. They could be less than a minute apart, but be in different minutes. 

`2013-05-17 12:00:45 and 2013-05-17 12:01:15'
These are less than a minute apart, but would be in different groupings. Same thing would go for timestamps at the end and start of an hour for example.

Comment: I've updated my query, what do you think about that? Instead of a static time frame, I'm giving a "barrier" of 5 minute windows from the start of any event date, you can adjust it in the condition for the left join as desired. I will add though, my approach does have the potential that entries will exist in multiple time segments, depending on how forgiving you make the 5 minute barrier